# Connecting HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, upload

I am trying to upload a file into a folder called directory. I have the HTML code for an  uploading form and once i've selected the desired file and I press upload, the PHP code is displayed in the browser and the file is not uploaded at all.

I am new to PHP. I have done HTML and CSS before. Possibly a little bit of Javascript, but not PHP. I put my uploader.php in a separate file than the HTML code. They are both below:

myHTML.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>

<?php
include 'uploader.php';
?>

<p>  
<h1> Advanced Tablet Based Visualization of Volumetric Data </h1>
</p>

 <p>
 Available files:
 </p>
 HELLO WORLD!!
 <form action="">
 <input type="button" value="Open"> <input type="button" value="Delete">
 </form>

 <hr />

 <p>
 <!-- Upload file source code: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php -->

 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>

 <br /> <br />
 <hr />
 Last Updated: October 24, 2011

 <br />
 Sponsored by:
 University of Notre Dame <img src="ndLogo" alt="ND logo" width="32" height="32"s />        
 <br />
 </p>

 </html>
 </body>
```

uploader.php:

```
// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "uploads/";

 /* Add the original filename to our target path.  
 Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */  
 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

 $target_path = "uploads/";

 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
     echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
     " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: try naming your "myHTML.html" to "myHTML.php" instead. Or else the server will read the files as normal html.

Comment: Does your server parse `.html` files using the PHP parser?

Comment: The HTML and PHP code appear to be correct.  I suspect you may have a permissions issue on your server.  First make sure that the "uploads" folder exists in the same parent folder as uploader.php.  Then, CHMOD it to 755 or 777 (world-writable) and try again.

Comment: Also, I can't see any reason to `include()` the file at the beginning of your HTML page.  It offers no useful purpose there.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I think you are correct, but becouse of that hes new to php, it's just easier to rename it with the extension .php at the end.

Comment: And, finally, you'll need to begin uploader.php with <?php on its own line (to tell the server to begin processing PHP code)

Comment: @Beijer - I didn't suggest that wasn't an option...

Comment: I added <?php and ?> to uploader.php and I took the php out of the html file and it still does the same thing. 
when i tried renaming my .html file to .php, the choose and upload buttons disappeared so I changed it back.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I never said you weren't. Just pointed out that it's better to learn the new people about the simple things before asking them about parsers.

Comment: @Beijer - I disagree only in that the OP cannot understand the problem they are facing if they don't understand their `.html` file isn't getting *parsed* (whatever that means, right?).

Answer (score 6):

The upload.php file needs to start with the php start tag.

```
<?php
```

Also the .html file should have the .php extension, as most web-servers use the file extension to determine how to handle a request.

Answer (score 1):

What i see is that in your first file (which is an HTML file) you have PHP code
That doesn't work that way :)
Unless you setup your web server to treat HTML files as PHP, you will need to rename your first file to *.php
This should get you going

Answer (score 1):

This won't be work inside an HTML file (unless the server is configured to do so):

```
<?php
    include 'uploader.php';
?>
```

You should change the extension from `html` to `php`